# OpenCart Issue With Cardinity Payment openssl_encrypt():

Tags: php, opencart

Good evening everyone!

I am getting a strange warning while trying to buy via credit card. Am using Cardinity payment gateway. OpenCart 3.0.2.0. PHP 7.2.0. Quickcheckout by MarketInSG. What happens is when you click on button Pay Now, it loads for a couple of seconds and then button is returned back to initial Pay Now state. Here is warning message:

`PHP Warning: openssl_encrypt(): Using an empty Initialization Vector (iv) is potentially insecure and not recommended in .../system/library/encryption.php on line 23.`

My encryption.php looks like this:

```
    <?php
/**
 * @package     OpenCart
 * @author      Daniel Kerr
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2005 - 2017, OpenCart, Ltd. (https://www.opencart.com/)
 * @license     https://opensource.org/licenses/GPL-3.0
 * @link        https://www.opencart.com
*/

/**
* Encryption class
*/
final class Encryption {
    /**
     * 
     *
     * @param   string  $key
     * @param   string  $value
     * 
     * @return  string
     */ 
    public function encrypt($key, $value) {
        return strtr(base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($value, 'aes-256-cbc', hash('sha256', $key, true))), '+/=', '-_,');
    }

    /**
     * 
     *
     * @param   string  $key
     * @param   string  $value
     * 
     * @return  string
     */
    public function decrypt($key, $value) {
        return trim(openssl_decrypt(base64_decode(strtr($value, '-_,', '+/=')), 'aes-256-cbc', hash('sha256', $key, true)));
    }
}
```

Line 23 is this: `return strtr(base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($value, 'aes-256-cbc', hash('sha256', $key, true))), '+/=', '-_,');`

Then I browsed around forums and found altered encryption.php that looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     OpenCart
 * @author      Daniel Kerr
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2005 - 2017, OpenCart, Ltd. (https://www.opencart.com/)
 * @license     https://opensource.org/licenses/GPL-3.0
 * @link        https://www.opencart.com
*/

/**
* Encryption class
*/
final class Encryption {
    /**
     * 
     *
     * @param   string  $key
     * @param   string  $value
     * 
     * @return  string
     */ 
    public function encrypt($key, $value) {
        // Remove the base64 encoding from our key
        $encryption_key = base64_decode($value);

        // Generate an initialization vector        
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-gcm'));

        // Encrypt the data using AES 256 encryption in GCM mode using our encryption key and initialization vector.        
        $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($key, 'aes-256-gcm', $encryption_key, 0, $iv);

        // The $iv is just as important as the key for decrypting, so save it with our encrypted data using a unique separator (::)     
        return base64_encode($encrypted . '::' . $iv);
    }

    /**
     * 
     *
     * @param   string  $key
     * @param   string  $value
     * 
     * @return  string
     */
    public function decrypt($key, $value) {
        // Remove the base64 encoding from our key
        $encryption_key = base64_decode($value);

        // To decrypt, split the encrypted data from our IV - our unique separator used was "::"
        list($encrypted_data, $iv) = explode('::', base64_decode($key), 2);

        return openssl_decrypt($encrypted_data, 'aes-256-gcm', $encryption_key, 0, $iv);
    }
}
```

When I use modified encryption.php file, I get the following warning:

```
PHP Warning: openssl_encrypt(): A tag should be provided when using AEAD mode in ...system/library/encryption.php on line 30
```

Line 30 is this: `$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($key, 'aes-256-gcm', $encryption_key, 0, $iv);`

Since my coding skills are limited, I don't know what else to do? To contact hosting company or Cardinity? Any help will be hugely appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Unless you're intention is to  reprogram opencart, it seems like your question should be directed to opencart.

Comment: Devon, I have tried on OpenCart forum, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The cardinity plugin uses opencarts provided encrypt library, which is still using deprecated functions.

When using this there is a PHP warning that mess up ajax json responses. If you want to get around this issue.

set

```
error_reporting(0);
```

right before wherever there is a use of encrypt()

```
error_reporting(0);
$this->encryption->encrypt(...)
```

The last patch should automatically fix this
https://github.com/cardinity/cardinity-opencart/releases/tag/3.0.x-3dsv2-patch1